# imeOptions actionDone with Android 2.3

Tags: android

I have a few EditTexts where I've set the imeOptions to actionDone.  When I run my application in the emulator using either Android 2.1 or Android 2.2, the enter key on the virtual keyboard becomes "done."

However, (and I've not tested this in the emulator), when I run my application on my phone, which is running Android 2.3 (straight 2.3, Nexus S), the enter key on the virtual keyboard is still a return button and pressing it enters a newline into the EditText.

How can I make the return key on the virtual keyboard say and behave as "done" in Android 2.3?

Comment: how about call `setSingleLine()` in java code or specify `android:singleLine="true"` in xml?

Comment: This makes the "done" button appear, but the text does not wrap and the EditText is forced to be a single line.  I want an EditText that wraps and has the "done" button.  It behaves appropriately on 2.1 and 2.2, but not on 2.3.

Comment: It seems to be kind of a bug since 2.3.4. Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218574/android-nexus-s-edittext-settings-ignored-2-3-4

BTW thanks kingori, that is good enough for my app.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented as below and it works great for me.
Try out it might help you out.

> ```
>   EditText m_etDone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.am_etDone);  
> EditText m_etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.am_etSearch);   
> m_etDone.setOnEditorActionListener(new DoneOnEditorActionListener());   
> m_etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new DoneOnEditorActionListener());                         
>      class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {    
> @Override
> public boolean onEditorAction(TextView p_v, int p_actionId, KeyEvent   p_event) {
>     if (p_actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) 
>  {
>     InputMethodManager m_imm = (InputMethodManager)p_v.getContext()        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
>     m_imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(p_v.getWindowToken(), 0);
>             return true;
>         }
>         else if(p_actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)
>         {
>             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Search Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             return true;
>         }
>     return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

Layout file:

> ```
> <EditText 
>     android:id="@+id/am_etDone"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:hint="Enter some text"
>     android:imeOptions="actionNext"
>     android:singleLine="true"
>     android:imeActionLabel="Done"/>    
> <EditText 
>     android:id="@+id/am_etSearch"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:hint="Enter search text"
>     android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
>     android:singleLine="true"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/am_etDone"
>     android:imeActionLabel="Search"/>
> ```